# What are the options to get filter on union querysets behavior with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.2

Basically the problem I have: I need an option or alternative approach to filter on annotated fields on union queryset.

I have the following simplified models setup:

```
class Course(Model):
    groups = ManyToManyField(through=CourseAssignment)


class CourseAssignment(Model):
    course = ForeignKey(Course)
    group = ForeignKey(Group)
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher)


class Lesson(Model):
    course = ForeignKey(Course, related_name='lessons')


class AssignmentProgress(Model):
    lesson = ForeignKey(related_name='progresses')
    course_assignment = ForeignKey(CourseAssignment)
    student = ForeignKey(Student)
    group = ForeignKey(Group)
    status = CharField(choices=(
                ('on_check', 'On check'), 
                ('complete', 'Complete'),
                ('assigned', 'Assigned'),
            ))
    deadline = DateTimeField()
    checked_date = DateTimeField()
```

I need to display a statistics on assignment progresses grouped by lessons and groups for which courses assigned. Here is a my initial queryset, note that lessons are repeated in final result, the difference is in annotated data:

```
def annotated_lessons_queryset():
    lessons = None
    for course_assignment in CourseAssignment.objects.all():
        qs = Lesson.objects.filter(
            course=course_assignment.course
        ).annotate(
            completed_progresses=Count(
                'progresses',
                filter=Q(group=course_assignment.group),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            ),
            on_check=Exists(
                AssignmentProgress.objects.filter(
                    lesson=OuterRef('id'), group=course_assignment.group, status='on_check'
                )
            )
        )
        lessons = qs if lessons is None else lessons.union(qs)
    return lessons
```

I canon use | OR  operator here, because it returns only distinct lesson values.
So far this works until I try filter all the lessons with annotated status on_check:

```
qs = annotated_lessons_queryset().filter(on_check=True)
```

Which fails with the error:

```
raise NotSupportedError(
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Calling QuerySet.filter() after union() is not supported.
```

Please, suggest a workaround or another approach to make this queryset filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't pulled this in and tried it out yet, but as the error message states you have to use union() last. This is a bit complicated as "Lessons can be repeated" in this queryset. So I would suggest using a list comprehension to get what you need out.

```py
qs = annotated_lessons_queryset()
filtered = [lesson for lesson in qs if lesson.on_check]
```